# Running code on Symfony kernel initialisation

Tags: php, symfony

How can some code in a bundle be executed after booting the Symfony2 kernel?

- The code must be run before a request is handled or console command is run.
- The code must be executed once, even when the kernel handles multiple requests during its lifetime.
- The code must be able to access the bundle configuration. It may therefore not be run to early in the proces.

The reason I need this is that I need to register a stream wrapper. I need to be able to use the bundle configuration since the stream wrapper definitions are defined in the config.

I tried the following:

- Implementing the constructor of the bundle class. (This does not work, not all bundles are initialised at this point)
- Creating event listeners for `kernel.request` and `console.command` (This will cause the code to be executed multiple times when the kernel handles multiple requests during its lifetime.)

Comment: This question is a little short on information. Can you share what you have tried, and what problems you have run into?

Comment: @JayBlanchard: I don't really know what I could tell you more. I explained what I want to achieve and why. And I gave two options I have tried including the problems I encountered with those options.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can override the `boot` method of your bundle.

```
class MyBundle extends Bundle
{
    public function boot()
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can register one service as event listener for both `kernel.request` and `console.command`. It will be fired from console and from HTTP request.